# mejorando codigo con reduce

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

hace unos dias me un miembro de aca me ayudo con un codigo, pero quede con muchas inetrrogantes en relacion al tema, estoy nuevo en esto, quisiera hacer un codigo que me traiga un solo arreglo de json y no varios arreglos, aqui el codigo para ver si alguien me puede ayudar:

```
  var comparaPago = (lista) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var listaPagos = Pagos.find({
                "user_id": lista.user,
                "fecha_pago": {
                    "$lt": lista.createdAt
                }
            }, (err, registrosEncontrados) => {
                if (!err) {

                    return registrosEncontrados

                }
            }
            ).sort({ fecha_pago: -1 })
                .limit(1)
            resolve(listaPagos);

        });


        ListarUsuariosMaxDate.then(response => {
            if (response) {
                const promise = Promise.all(response.reduce(comparaPago));
                       .then(listOfResults => {
                        return res.status(200).json(listOfResults)    

                       }).catch(error => {
                        console.error(error);
                    })
            }
        }).catch(console.error);
```

ListarUsuariosMaxDate es una funcion que me devbuelve iuna lista, funciona bien pero al realizar este codigo del llamado de la siguiente funcion, ,me arroja en json de la siguiente manera:

```
[
    [],
    [],
    [
        {
            "_id": "5963228a02c0df1d188694e1",
            "updatedAt": "2017-07-10T19:06:05.681Z",
            "createdAt": "2017-07-10T06:45:30.304Z",
            "user_id": "579e4083a48b47d5331b50d4",

    ],
    [
        {
            "_id": "5964d8a95b40b919f88f070c",
            "updatedAt": "2017-07-11T13:54:49.963Z",
            "createdAt": "2017-07-11T13:54:49.963Z",
            "user_id": "595e55418dfcf22b2398790d",

        }
    ]
```

quisiera un solo arreglo json y sin los valores nulos, eso si, no puedo utilizar la funcion flat por versiones del node:

```
[
  {
            "_id": "5963228a02c0df1d188694e1",
            "updatedAt": "2017-07-10T19:06:05.681Z",
            "createdAt": "2017-07-10T06:45:30.304Z",
            "user_id": "579e4083a48b47d5331b50d4"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5964d8a95b40b919f88f070c",
            "updatedAt": "2017-07-11T13:54:49.963Z",
            "createdAt": "2017-07-11T13:54:49.963Z",
            "user_id": "595e55418dfcf22b2398790d",

        }
    ]
```

gracias y diculpen mi ignoraciancia

Comment: Hola, puedes publicar la estructura de tu esquema? De donde obtienes `pagos`.

Comment: Y que contiene `response`?

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, response me trae la data de otro proceso pero la que queria adaptar era la listOfResults, con el codigo lo pude hacer y gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 1):

Conseguí hacerlo con este código, lo dejo por acá por si a alguien le sirve:

```
    const flatArray = arr => arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val))

    ListarUsuariosMaxDate.then(response => {
        if (response) {
            const promise = Promise.all(response.map(comparaPago));
            promise.then(flatArray)
                   .then(listOfResults => { 

                    return res.status(200).json(listOfResults)    

                   }).catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                })
        }
    }).catch(console.error);
```